# How do I make friends with Wolves who have defriended me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have this problem with wolves, happening within on Single Player mode.

What happens is, I friend the wolf with between 1-5 bones. Simple right?

Then, I log out of MC, and come back a couple days later.   I go to my wolf, who I last left sitting in place.  Right clicking does nothing.  I can't get him to get up, he won't respond.  I tried drowning him and running away, in hopes he would "teleport" to me, but he just stands there and drowns.  Fine.  I kill him in the end.

Is this a glitch?  Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few glitches with wolves:

- Who they respond to is case sensitive, whereas your login is not. Try to use the same capitalisation when logging in.
- When logging in, they appear to be sitting but are actually standing, try right clicking multiple times to fix the animation glitch.
- An extension to the first glitch, when playing in offline mode, your username is Player. This ne change will cause wolves not to recognise you.

Comment: Thanks.  Does this mean I have to kill the wolf?